# The search field in jqGrid doesn’t return the date: 20-03-2020

Tags: jqgrid, jqgrid-php

The search field in jqGrid doesn’t return the date 20-03-2020. For other dates it's OK, but this date is not being returned. Why?

```
{
  colModel:[{ 
    name:'data_reg', 
    index:'data_reg', 
    align:"center",
    editable:false, 
    formatter:'date',
    formatoptions:{newformat:'d-m-Y'},
    width:10
  }]
}
```

Comment: Are you certain it’s just this date? And not any date where, for instance, the day is over 12? The reason I ask is that it may not be recognizing the `formatoptions` and thus searching it as an American style `m-d-Y`, in which case `20-03-2020` wouldn’t show up as a valid date—but, in that case, neither would e.g. `13-02-2020`. Alternatively, are you certain that the `m` in `formatoptions` accommodates leading zeroes? In other words, does it find `20-3-2020`? Some format strings differentiate between e.g. `d` and `dd`, though conventions vary.

Comment: thanks for the reply, I tried to delete the formatoptions function too, but it doesn't work.
it is only that date the others work.

Comment: Any example with live data will be greatly appreciated, otherwise I can't help.

Comment: do you want access to the software?